# How to display a [] in a jekyll code paragraph

Tags: ruby, markdown, jekyll

I'm trying to put a section of code in a Jekyll markdown file. It contains `[]` square brackets, like: `object["xxx"]`. I insert a `\` before the `[` and `]` to prevent a ruby compiler error, but on the compiled page the `\` is displayed.

Does anyone know how to show `[]` in a code paragraph?

Comment: Which markdown engine are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Maruku markdown engine I can escape the [] characters by surrounding the text in `<pre>` tags.

e.g.

```
<pre>
   object["xxx"]
</pre>
```

or indent by 4 our more characters

```
    object["xxx"]
```